# How can expand this two folders in wiki

Tags: html, css, wiki

I am trying to create expand pages in the wiki page. but now when I expand the first one the next one automatically changed to collapse.

How can I modify the code that when I expand the first parent folder "Measure"
the child folder "Current Year" still is "Expand" not collapse automatically?

Thank you very much.

**Available Folders and Columns**

```
 {| role="presentation" class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" border="0" style="text-align: left;"
 | <strong>Measure&nbsp;</strong>
 |-
 |
 {| role="presentation" class="mw-collapsible Innercollapse" border="0" style="text-align: left;"
 | <strong>Current Year&nbsp;</strong>
 |-
 |}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.